# Printing Binary Search Tree with numbered nodes

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I want to do an InOrder traversal of a BST and print the nodes. I can print the tree just fine but I can't get the numbering right.

Here is all the code if anyone wants to compile and give it a shot. Thank you!

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>



struct Node_h {
    int start_addr;
    int size;

    struct Node_h* left;
    struct Node_h* right;
};

struct Node_h* newHoleNode(int st, int size) {
    struct Node_h* tmp = (struct Node_h*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node_h));
    tmp->start_addr = st;
    tmp->size = size;
    tmp->left = NULL;
    tmp->right = NULL;
    return tmp;
}

int compare(struct Node_h* lhs, struct Node_h* rhs) {
    if(lhs->size != rhs->size) 
        return (lhs->size < rhs->size) ? -1 : 1;
    else if(lhs->start_addr == rhs->start_addr)
        return 0;
    else
        return (lhs->start_addr < rhs->start_addr) ? -1 : 1;
}

struct Node_h* insertHole(struct Node_h* cur, struct Node_h* add) {
    /* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
    if (cur == NULL) 
        return add;

    /* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
    if (compare(add, cur) == -1) {
        cur->left  = insertHole(cur->left, add);
    }
    else if(compare(add, cur) == 1) {
        cur->right = insertHole(cur->right, add);
    }

    /* return the (unchanged) node pointer */
    return cur;
}

int printHoles(struct Node_h* cur, int num) {
    if(cur == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    int t = 1 + num;
    t += printHoles(cur->left, num);
    printf("Hole %d: start location = %d, size = %d\n", t, cur->start_addr, cur->size);
    t += printHoles(cur->right, t);
    return t;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));   // should only be called once
    int pid = 0;
    struct Node_h* root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
        int size = rand() % 10000;
        root = insertHole(root, newHoleNode(pid++, size));
    }
    printHoles(root, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The numbering is always either massive random +/- numbers or something like that. Help!

Hole 1: start location = 168, size = 12

Hole 2: start location = 665, size = 12

Hole 4: start location = 506, size = 14

Hole 5: start location = 908, size = 30

Hole 11: start location = 498, size = 31

Hole 13: start location = 340, size = 38

Hole 14: start location = 378, size = 44

Hole 29: start location = 303, size = 54

Hole 30: start location = 948, size = 58

Hole 60: start location = 503, size = 70

Comment: What do you mean by numbered nodes?

Comment: They should be printed: "Hole 1 ....\nHole 2....\nHole 3...." and so on. In ascending order of course.

Comment: @D.Lamkin When you want numbering do you mean in increasing order (for whatever the BST uses to order the nodes)? So number according to traversal order?

Comment: Yes, it's basically just a line number.

Comment: @D.Lamkin I'm not seeing anything wrong with your initial code (just printHoles code). What is the output you're getting, and what is your expected output? Can you provide a testcase where it's failing?

Comment: @D.Lamkin FYI you can use the following pattern so you don't have to type `struct Node_h` everywhere: `typedef struct Node_h { ... } Node;`

Comment: @BlackSheep in the code I show I add 1000 nodes with random sizes/pid(the key). When I print I get the lines I just added to my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160144/discussion-between-d-lamkin-and-blacksheep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// num is the number of nodes printed so far
// return the number of nodes printed so far
int printHoles(struct Node_h* cur, int num) {
    if(NULL == cur) {
        // last printed not changed
        return num;
    }
    num = printHoles(cur->left, num);
    printf("%d. size = %d\n", num + 1, cur->size);
    num = printHoles(cur->right, num + 1);
    return num;
}
```

We can use `num` to track the number of nodes printed so far. Without using `t` this should be clearer and correct.

Answer (score 2):

Make `num` a pointer and increment directly after the node is visited. With the following modification, `printHoles` no longer needs to return `int`:

```
void printHoles(struct Node_h* cur, int* num) {
  if (cur == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  printHoles(cur->left, num);
  printf("Hole %d: start location = %d, size = %d\n", *num, cur->start_addr, cur->size);
  (*num)++;
  printHoles(cur->right, num);
}
```

Comment: This is another valid approach, but not valid c code

Comment: @Ctx Right. I forgot it was C.

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite your function like

```
int printHoles(struct Node_h* cur, int num) {
    if(cur == NULL) {
        return num;
    }
    num = printHoles(cur->left, num) + 1;
    printf("Hole %d: start location = %d, size = %d\n", num, cur->start_addr, cur->size);
    num = printHoles(cur->right, num);
    return num;
}
```

it should correctly track the number of values outputted. Before each `printf()`-call, the num is now incremented by one and each recursive call returns, how many values were output up to then. This should do what you expect.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct because if I am at a node N {size=3, left=NULL, right=Node(5)}, and num=4, then I print `9. size=3. `. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: It's definitely not correct for any non-trivial BST.

Comment: @BlackSheep well, you just copied my answer and spotted my mistake with "+=" instead of "=", gratulations ;)

Comment: I actually was independently solving the question and came up with that solution after getting it to work on my test inputs. But it's neat that you think I copied you instead

Comment: @BlackSheep Oh, ok, sorry, I surely misinterpreted the coincidency ;)